# camel-quarkus-amqp: Erroneous proceed messages not requeued / route not transactional

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus, amqp

**Problem:**

When the further processing of a message fails, than the message is not requeued but just lost for good. Otherwise everything is working fine.

**Environment:**

Quarkus application on AKS with camel-quarkus-amqp, queue = Azure service bus

We have similar applications to that one, running on a jboss server with the same configuration (service bus queue with same properties, similar camel route setup) that are not showing that behaviour.

**Code:**

The application was previously built based on quarkus 1.11.3.Final but even after an update to 2.7.6.Final, the behaviour is the same.

from *pom.xml* (standard like from code generation):

```
<properties>
  ...
  <quarkus.platform.version>2.7.6.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-amqp</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-bean</artifactId>
  </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

*application.properties:*

```
quarkus.qpid-jms.url=failover:(amqps://xyz.servicebus.windows.net)
quarkus.qpid-jms.username=xxx
quarkus.qpid-jms.password=xxx
```

*Implementation - Consumer:*

```
public class MessageConsumer extends RouteBuilder {

    @Inject private UpdateService updateService;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("amqp:queue:" + "queueName")
            .routeId(MessageConsumer.class.getName() + ".consumeQueue")
            .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(UUID.fromString(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class))))
            .bean(updateService);
    }
}
```

*Implementation - Producer:*

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MessageRepository {

    @Inject ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public void sendMessage(UUID uuid) {
        try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
            context.createProducer().send(context.createQueue("queueName"), uuid.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Invalid message");
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

What do I need to change / add to get messages requeued (not acknowledged) if an exception will be throw inside the bean processing of `updateService` in the camel route?

Comment: As it looks there is no support for transacted routes in camel-quarkus for the version I am forced to use, just from 3.4.0 upwards: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15108 . Thus, this stuff well needs to be done in plain Java

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue here is that you need to enable transactions on the route so that the consumption of the message that fails will trigger a rollback of the transaction when an error is thrown.

There is considerable documentation about this and how transaction are managed in the Camel docs [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/transactional-client.html).

Comment: "Traditionally a JTA Transaction Manager are included in JEE application servers. However, when running microservice applications with Spring Boot, or Quarkus, then a 3rd-party JTA transaction manager can be embedded and used." - Does I understand that correctly that you get it for free when running on JBoss whereas you need to take care for it when running as a Quarkus standalone application (like it is on AKS)?

Comment: I'm not a quarkus expert so I can't really comment on it but it sounds like you need to provide your own solution for global transactions, although in your case perhaps simple local transactions would work.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a lack of transactional support for AMQP in camel-quarkus in versions below 3.4.0, I needed to do that plain without camel. Here is my implementation as reference for others maybe facing the same or similar problem.

Edit 2023-03-11:

This solution has a big flaw since the acknowledgement will be applied to all messages of the same session. If there were some failed before and than a successfully one went through, all messages will be acknowledged, also the failed ones. I am working on a solution for that now...

Edit 2023-04-06:

I removed the code from above and replaced it with the following one:

```
public class MessageConsumer implements Runnable {

    private static final long WAIT_UNTIL_RECONNECT = 30000; // 30 seconds

    @Inject private UpdateService updateService;
    @Inject ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    private final ExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) { scheduler.submit(this); }
    void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) { scheduler.shutdown(); }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // loop here to make sure that it will reconnect to the queue in case of disconnect
        while (true) {
            try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()) {
                connection.start();
                consume(connection);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in connection", e);
                Thread.sleep(WAIT_UNTIL_RECONNECT);
            }
        }
    }

    private void consume(Connection connection) throws JMSException {
        log.info("Starting queue session...");
        try (Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED)) {
            Destination queue = session.createQueue(messagingProperties.getQueue());
            while (true) {
                try (javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue)) {
                    Message message = consumer.receive();
                    try {
                        handleMessage(message);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        session.rollback();
                        log.error("Error in message processing", e);
                    }
                    session.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleMessage(Message message) {
        if (message == null) return;
        updateService.update(UUID.fromString(message.getBody(String.class)));
        message.acknowledge();
    }
}
```